# Mod_rewrite rule for rewriting language to query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the following in .htaccess to transform a language specified in the url to a query string:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/(.*)$  $2?language=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It works as expected when I enter any of:

```
mydomain.com/en/
mydomain.com/en/about/
mydomain.com/en/about/index.php
```

But if I enter this:

```
mydomain.com/en/about
```

(no trailing slash), the browser redirects to

```
mydomain.com/en/about/?language=en
```

Which is the correct destination except that it should be an internal rewrite. I don't want to see this in the browser location bar.

What am I missing?

Comment: is `about` a folder? mod_dir redirects requests for folders that are missig the trailing slash

Comment: yes, `about` is a folder. the problem is that mod_dir is turning the whole thing into a redirect, making public the part that I wanted to keep internal (the query string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to turn off mod_dir and handle the trailing slashes internally. Maybe something like this:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# handle post-rewrite trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R]

# handle pre-rewrite trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2 -d
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/(.*[^/])$ /$1/$2/ [L,R]

RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/(.*)$  $2?language=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This should take a request like `mydomain.com/en/about` and redirect it to `mydomain.com/en/about/` before your last rule internally rewrites it.

Comment: Thanks. This seemed to work even without `DirectorySlash Off` (because you are adding the slash and redirecting, mod_dir never has a chance to look at it). Is there a reason to disable it?

Comment: I believe it would be best practice to use R=301 for this type of redirect?

Comment: @JasonWood in my experience, mod_dir processes the request before mod_rewrite, that may not be the case for you (may have something to do with order modules are loaded?). For redirection, R=301 is probably better, but keep in mind you're redirecting URLs that don't exist (`/en/about` isn't really a folder, but what it internally rewrites to *is*), so I guess it comes down to how your implementation.